# Visual Studio 2010 Accessing a Variable Breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I am trying to get Visual Studio to stop on a breakpoint anytime a variable I am calling it accessed.

For example:

```
float someNum=0;
```

is initialized but never changed. If I say,

```
float someOtherNum=someNum;
```

OR

```
someFunction(someNum);
```

How can I have Visual Studio stop at this reference?  Should I be using breakpoints for this or is there some other tool that Visual Studio has?

Please not the reason that I am not just looking for "someNum" is because it is simplified from someObject->someOtherObject->someNum and there are lots of calls with different structures accessing this variable.

Edit:

I have used the visual studio Data Breakpoint.  This does not seem to be a solution to my problem as the Data Breakpoint seems to be reliant on changing the value of the variable and not just when the memory is accessed for its variable.

Comment: The VS debugger doesn't support this.  You could just right-click "someNum" and choose Find All References and set breakpoints on the lines it shows.  If this is a frequent need then clearly a function instead of a variable is what you want.  Avoid global variables, they are evil.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a watchpoint in VS. Here is a link to a tutorial: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPBnbhbVFjY`